# Parse a line of Markdown, without <p>

Tags: templating, markup, markdown

Is there a way to parse a line of Markdown within Twig – without the surrounding 
`<p>` tags?

I see there is a StringHelper method called [ParseMarkdownLine](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/StringHelper#parseMarkdownLine-detail) that does exactly what I'd like, but I haven't found a way to invoke it in my templates.

Comment: `{{ item | markdown | replace('<p>','') | replace('</p>','') | raw }}` works for a single line, but it does not feel right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're here looking for a Craft 3 answer, the [Wordsmith plugin](https://wordsmith.docs.topshelfcraft.com/guide/markdown.html#markdown) offers the same ability to only parse inline and not include paragraph tags:

```
{{ entry.title|markdown(inlineOnly=true) }}
```

Comment: As of Craft 3.5, the inlineOnly directive works with core too

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [Parsedown](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Parsedown) plugin by P&T, it provides a line mode to not output any wrapping `<p>` tags.

```
{{ entry.title|parsedown('line') }}
```